# Retrieving OneToOne related QuerySet in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search, django-queryset

Background:

I'm using djorm-ext-pgfulltext extension to do full-text-search using Postgres on a title field for one of my models (Bookmark).

```
class Bookmark(TimeStampModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    # other fields

    search_index = VectorField()

    objects = SearchManager(
        fields = ('title'),
        config = 'pg_catalog.english',
        search_field = 'search_index',
        auto_update_search_field = True
    )
```

I have another model called SharedBookmark that is OneToOne related to the Bookmark.

```
class SharedBookmark(TimeStampedModel):
    bookmark = models.OneToOneField(Bookmark)
    # other fields
```

I am able to do a search through my Bookmark instances using:

```
Bookmark.objects.search(query)
```

which returns a QuerySet of Bookmarks.

My Question:

What would be one possible "best practice" approach to retrieve the SharedBookmarks that are OneToOne related to the QuerySet of Bookmarks returned? I feel like I am missing something fundamental... I tried doing

```
bookmarks = Bookmark.objects.search(query).values_list('id', flat=True)
shared_bookmarks = SharedBookmark.objects.filter(bookmark__pk__in=bookmarks)
```

and besides seeming possibly convoluted, I received a database error **invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "bookmarks_bookmark"**

**Updated with full stack trace and error:**

```
Traceback:
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/derek/Development/skillfare/skillfare/bookmarks/views.py" in search
  88.                 return render(request, 'main_page.html', variables)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  177.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  124.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  63.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  156.         return self.render_template(self.template, context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render_template
  138.         output = template.render(context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  283.             if match:
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __nonzero__
  141.         return type(self).__bool__(self)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __bool__
  135.             next(iter(self))
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _result_iter
  123.                 self._fill_cache()
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fill_cache
  939.                     self._result_cache.append(next(self._iter))
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _safe_iterator
  344.             for item in iterator:
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  301.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  775.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  41.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py" in execute
  58.             six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/home/derek/.virtualenvs/skillfare/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py" in execute
  54.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /search/
Exception Value: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "bookmarks_bookmark"
LINE 1: ...ECT U0."id" FROM "bookmarks_bookmark" U0 WHERE ( ("bookmarks...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "u0".
```

Comment: Error indicates you have an error in the `query`. Also, you can do `SharedBookmark.objects.filter(bookmark__in=Bookmark.objects.search(query))`

Comment: @karthikr Thanks for the syntax for performing the filter, but I'm still receiving the same error. I can do Bookmark.objects.search(query) with no problems. I guess this problem could be related to me having performed a migration when adding search_indexes with existing data that may not be initialized correctly. Complete error invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "bookmarks_bookmark"
LINE 1: ...ECT U0."id" FROM "bookmarks_bookmark" U0 WHERE ( ("bookmarks...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "u0".

Comment: Here `bookmarks_` I cant see the full query, but you might have to replace that with `U0`

Comment: @karthikr Can you clarify what I should replace with U0? Do you know if this may be an issue with django?

Answer (score 2):

As stated by kathikr, the following nested query can be used to retrieve the SharedBookmarks that are OneToOne related to the QuerySet of Bookmarks returned.

```
SharedBookmark.objects.filter(bookmark__in=Bookmark.objects.search(query))
```

But when using this query with djorm-ext-pgfulltext, it produces an "invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table..." error. According to https://groups.google.com/d/topic/django-users/5PrcxbF38Ag/discussion this is most likely caused by djorm-ext-pgfulltext not supporting alias relabeling - specifically the use of extra() in the search method defined in djorm-ext-pgfulltext. The following statement will force two separate queries that will avoid the error:

```
SharedBookmark.objects.filter(bookmark__in=list(Bookmark.objects.search(query)))
```